# Xcode 6.2 UI tests don't run from Jenkins on simulator

Tags: xcode, jenkins, vnc

i have got UI tests, and they don't run from Jenkins, but from current VM, when i log in via VNC i can start and them passed. My nodes connected to Jenkins via jnlp, vnc session is running. users are the same as in jenkins and local vm

```
xcodebuild -scheme 'QVC - QA'  -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone 6' test

12:38:28 Touch /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QVC-chdwbiakejemyxbyyafcpmiavikg/Build/Products/Acceptance-iphonesimulator/QVCTests.xctest
12:38:28     cd /Users/.../workspace/qvc-test/project/Sources
12:38:28     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/bin:/Users/.../ci-tools_new/xcpretty/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant/bin"
12:38:28     /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QVC-chdwbiakejemyxbyyafcpmiavikg/Build/Products/Acceptance-iphonesimulator/QVCTests.xctest
12:38:28 
12:40:28 2015-04-22 12:40:28.456 xcodebuild[53002:100b] [MT] IDEUnitTestsOperationsObserverDebug: Unable to get debug console for logging target process thread state.
12:40:28 
12:40:28 Testing failed:
12:40:28    Test target QVCTests encountered an error (Canceling tests due to timeout in Waiting for test process to check in... If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/xx/l0mp3szd0bx332cv3qrw1v3h0000gq/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-04-22_12:37:12-u1STY7.log)
12:40:28 ** TEST FAILED **
```

And on local machine i've run the same command but tests SUCCEEDED

Answer (score 0):

R u running it on Jenkins slave with MacOS? If yes, you should connect your slave as JNLP, not ssh. XCode doesn't allow remote execution via SSH, but via JNLP all works ok.